# Attached Error Event to User Task in Camunda-BPM

Tags: bpmn, camunda

Is it possible in Camunda-BPM to trigger an Error Event, which is attached to a User Task?

What I got looks something like this:

[image]

According to BPMN 2.0.2 there are no restrictions on using an attached Error Event on a User Task, but I ddnt find any solution to this problem so far.

Comment: For BPMN modeling questions (especially if it is "camunda relevant", I would rather go to the [camunda network](http://network.camunda.org/forum).
Diagrams can be uploaded, elements commented and model reviewed.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you zeropaper, I'll have a look there for sure.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible via the taskService.handleBpmnError method in Spring boot and https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.13/reference/rest/task/post-bpmn-error/ if you're using the REST API